# Cartan's proof that there is a smallest positive zero of cosine function

Tags: analysis, pi

In section 3, paragraph 3 of Chapter 1 of his "Elementary theory of analytic functions of one or several complex variables", Cartan wants to prove that $\cos y$ vanishes for a certain value of $y$ which is $>0$ and then deduce that there is a smallest such number so that he can define it as $\pi /2$. Here is how he goes:

> When $y=0$, $\cos y$ is equal to $1$; since $\cos y$ is a continuous function, there exists a $y_0\gt0$ such that $\cos y\gt0$ for $0\le y \le y_0$. Hence $\sin y$, whose derivative is $\cos y$, is a strictly increasing function in the interval $[0,y_0]$. Put $\sin y_0=a$. Suppose in fact that $\cos y\gt0$ for $y_0 \le y \le y_1$; we have
> $\cos y_1 -\cos y_0 =- \int_{y_0}^{y_1}\sin y\,dy$.
> However, $\sin y\ge a$, because $\sin y$ is an increasing function in the interval $[y_0,y_1]$ where its derivative is $\gt 0$, thus $\int_{y_0}^{y_1} \sin y\,dy \ge a(y_1 -y_0)$. By substituting this in the above equality and noting that $\cos y_1 \gt 0$, we find that $y_1 - y_0 \lt \frac1a \cos y_0$. This proves that $\cos y$ vanishes in the interval $[y_0,y_0+\frac1a \cos y_0]$.

The steps are clear, and in conclusion he proves that whenever $\cos y \gt 0$ on an interval $[y_0,y_1]$, we have $y_0 \lt y_1 \lt y_0+\frac1a \cos y_0$. How does this prove the result?

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about it is by contradiction. Suppose $\cos(x)$ never vanishes. Thus, for any $y_1$ we choose we will have that $\cos(x)>0$ in $[y_0,y_1]$. Note that this is because if $\cos(x) < 0$ somewhere then it will vanish by the intermediate value theorem (and we assumed $\cos(x)\neq 0$).

Now, by choosing $y_1 = y_0 + \frac{1}{a}\cos(y_0)$ we get a contradiction. Notice that this is a contradiction because the condition is (notice it's less then and not less then equal):
$$ y_1 < y_0 + \frac{1}{a}\cos(y_0)$$

Thus, we showed that $\{x > 0  :\cos(x)=0\}$ is non empty. Furthermore, it has an infimum. Thus we have $x_n \to x_\infty$ where $x_\infty$ is the infimum and $x_n\in \{x > 0  :\cos(x)=0\}$. By continuity of $\cos(x)$ we get $\cos(x_\infty)=0$ thus the infimum is a minimum.

Comment: It is clear that the infimum of this set would be an element of it(this set is the inverse image of the closed set {0} under the cosine function, hence it is closed so its infimum is an element of it). My only confusion was why does cosine vanishes on the suggested interval. My thoughts were: it is at most possible for cosy to keep positive on $[y_0,y_0 +\frac{1a} cosy_0]$, to reach the desired result just take a further point(as you suggested) but this doesn't clear the confusion that he claims such a zero exists in this interval.

Comment: But I think now it is clearer: whenever $cosy>0$ for $y_0\leq y\le y_1$, $y_1$ must be less than $y_0+\frac{1}{a} cosy_0$ so there must exist a zero of $cosy$ between $y_1$ and $y_0+\frac{1}{a} cosy_0$?

Comment: @Stu I edited the answer accordingly to show what you have written more explicitly. The formatting of your comments is a bit weird so I can't read it well.